# How many circles (radius = 0.5) can fit in circle (radius = 35)?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

How many circles A **(radius = 0.5)** can fit in circle B **(radius = 35)**? I've been struggling a lot and couldn't find a solution so I decided to post it right here.

Comment: @Zubi The densest possible packing, which is $7$ circles arranged in a hexagon, has a density of $\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{3}$. Using this, we can get an upper bound of $(\pi * 35^2) / (\pi * 0.5^2) * \frac{1}{6} \sqrt{3} \approx 5658$.

Comment: @TobyMak It's a (very) open problem and difficult, too. Not just combinatorics and geometry. Have a look here http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci.html#overview

Comment: @TobyMak $5658\times 0.5^2\times \pi\approx 4443.78$ while $35^2\times \pi \approx 3848.45$ something is wrong :)

Comment: @Raffaele Hence, the answer is **4315 circles**, with $r=1/0.5/35=0.0142857<0.0143235$ ... impressive... http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci4315.html

Comment: @hyprfrcb never imagined it was so complex a problem! Actually the OP didn't specify that the packaging must be *optimal*, thus even $1$ could be an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I say $4315$ because I looked on  [this page](http://www.packomania.com/) and considering that $0.5/35\approx 0.0142857$ I looked in the second column and the radius of $4315$ packed circle was the closest to the value I found, namely about $0.0143235$, so there should be at least $4315$ circles non overlapping having radius $0.5$ in a circle having radius $35$. The picture below is with larger radius and has $1394$ circles.

[image]